# Apache mod_proxy/mod_rewrite geoip header issue

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, geoip, proxypass

I need to proxy pass a request from www.server.com to home.server.com to set a cookie. The home.server.com sets the geo location of the user.  However, when the request is passed from www.server.com to home.server.com, the geoip_* environment settings are either being dropped/stripped or ignored.

If I go directly to home.server.com, I see it setting correctly. It is not setting (empty) when I start from www.server.com.

```
<code>
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !SESSIONID=
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[a-z]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^[a-z]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://home.server.com [P,L]
</code>
```

Thank you for any advice/input! What am I missing?